# Smooth Unity jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Could you please help me modifying this code, so that the jump become smooth.
_rb.AddForce haven't worked for me like at all.

I know why is this happening, but dunno how to solve.
Maybe some async tasks with a delay or deltaTime tricks?

Thanks.

```
private void Update()
{
    _moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0);
    _moveVelocity = _moveInput * Speed;

    _jumpVelocity = new Vector2(0, 10) * 10f;


    if (_isGrounded == true)
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            _isJump = true;
        }
    }

    if (_moveInput.x == 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    _rb.MovePosition(_rb.position + _moveVelocity);

    if (_isJump)
    { 
        _rb.MovePosition(_rb.position + _jumpVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        Debug.Log("Jump");
        _isJump = false;
        _isGrounded = false;


    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
    {
        _isGrounded = true;
    }
}
```

Async, AddForce, for with counters.

Comment: You're using Time.fixedDeltaTime which is a fixed value that doesn't vary with the actual framerate. It would be smoother if the amount moved was directly related to how much time has passed since the previous frame, so you should try multiplying the velocity by Time.deltaTime instead.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TimeFrameManagement.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the jump. One trick is to add your gravity. (Five times larger than the original ~ -50). I usually don't use the `RigidBody`. If you want to do so, then add this line

```cs
// removing gravity
rb.AddForce(0, -Physics.gravity.y, 0);
// applying gravity 5 times larger
rb.AddForce(0, Physics.gravity.y * 5, 0);
```

I suggest that you watch [Brackeys video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc) for more detailed information.